# Construction of the travel time graph model from map data for GPS navigation

Tags: algorithm, graph, gps, dijkstra

Computing an itinerary for GPS is generally done by a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm for shortest path in a positively weighted graph (e.g. A*; I've been also told that GPS applications may ignore minor roads when computing the middle of the path). There are also approaches that "contract" the graph by extending it with precomputed "shortcuts".

However, I don't find information about how to build the graph from map data in the first place. Surely there must be methods for correctly estimating speed? Are there any references on this?

Answer (score -1):

Find map data that includes the speed limit.  On rural roads assume that every vehicle travels the speed limit.  On urban roads, the speed will have to be reduced during rush hours

Comment: I live in a mountaineous area. There are many roads that have nominal speed limits at the default legal speed limit (80 or 90 kph) but it's simply impossible to drive at that speed on these roads (too winding, too narrow so when you have to slow down for incoming traffic, and also one has to take slopes into account).